# excel vba: find the row of a cell with a certain value and put that row number in another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find the row of a cell with a certain value (the same value as `range("C1").value`) and put that row number in another cell.  I'm stuck on it for two hours.

My code as follows:
(I activated sheet1 before)

```
Set found = sheet1.Columns("B").Find(what:= sheet1.range("C1").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)       
sheet1.range("A2").value= found.Address
```

This code got error message `Object variable not set`

What is the source of this error?

Comment: Without seeing the worksheet or the rest of the code, I'd guess the search value wasn't found.

Comment: @Comintern19           thanks for your response.  The problem is that my eyes see B24 has the same value as the search value ( sheet1.range("C1").value), but the vba code doesn't give me the row-number which is 24 in this case.   ..................did I misunderstand the "search value" you are talking about?  Please help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B'cos the variable found is empty, since Find() doesn't find any matching values and not set anything in found variable.

```
Dim found As Range

Set found = Sheet1.Columns("B").Find(what:=Sheet1.Range("C1").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not found Is Nothing Then
    Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = found.Address
End If
```